# How to dynamically allocate vector and struct in a code?

Tags: c, vector, struct, malloc

I'm trying to allocate a struct and an array in the code below, but I have no idea how to proceed.
I'm trying to do this without adding other libraries.
It's in portuguese so I'm sorry if you don't understant the meaning.

```
struct RegistroAluno{
    int Matricula;
    char Nome[20];
    int AnoNascimento;
};

int main()
{
    int QuantidadeAlunos;
    
    printf("Quantos alunos serão armazenados?\n");
    scanf("%i", &QuantidadeAlunos);
    
    struct RegistroAluno P1[QuantidadeAlunos];
    struct *P1=(int *)malloc(QuantidadeAlunos*sizeof(struct));

    for(int i=0; i<QuantidadeAlunos; i++){
        printf("Qual a matrícula do aluno?\n");
        scanf("%i", &P1[i].Matricula);
    }/* I gotta do the same to all the other elements of the struct*/
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to allocate a struct and an array

Comment: You want to translate your program to English, and when it doesn't compile like your program then you want to tell us the error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate a variable length array (VLA) of `struct RegistroAluno` here:

```
    struct RegistroAluno P1[QuantidadeAlunos];
```

Alternatively, you can allocate the array dynamically like this:

```
    struct RegistroAluno *P1 = malloc(QuantidadeAlunos*sizeof(*P1));
```

Here the complete program with includes and error handling:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct RegistroAluno{
    int Matricula;
    char Nome[20];
    int AnoNascimento;
};

int main(void) {
    printf("Quantos alunos serão armazenados?\n");
    int QuantidadeAlunos;
    if(scanf("%i", &QuantidadeAlunos) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(QuantidadeAlunos < 1) {
        printf("QuantidadeAlunos must be > 0\n");
        return 1;
    }
    struct RegistroAluno *P1 = malloc(QuantidadeAlunos*sizeof(*P1));
    if(!P1) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<QuantidadeAlunos; i++){
        printf("Qual a matrícula do aluno?\n");
        if(scanf("%i", &P1[i].Matricula) != 1) {
            printf("scanf failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

and example session:

```
Quantos alunos serão armazenados?
2
Qual a matrícula do aluno?
3
Qual a matrícula do aluno?
4
```